# android java.lang.nullpointerexception

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am trying to do something like this in android . I mean i have password text box and i am trying make visible a text view if password is correct but i am continuously showing a exception `java.lang.nullpointerexception` here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    EditText Password;
    Button login;
    TextView txtDash;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass);
        login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.login);

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View V) {
                try {
                if (Password.getText().toString().equals("dsml"))
                {

                    txtDash.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    login.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    Password.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "invalid password - try again",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                }catch(Exception e){
                     //Log.e("log_tag", "Error"+e.toString());
                     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(),  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Please any one help to getout of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing to get a reference to txtDash before you use it.

```
txtDash = (View)findViewById(R.id.id_for_your_view);
```

Answer (score 1):

Give refrence of `txtDash` from xml layout file as like as Password,login

```
Password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass);
login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.login);

txtDash=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtdas); <<< You Forgot this line...
```